# What happened to Google Scholar search by subject area?

Tags: google-search, google-scholar

It was possible to restrict search in Google Scholar by subject area, e.g. it was possible to select *Engineering, Computer Science, and Mathematics* in Advanced Scholar Search, which had the same effect as including `as_subj=eng` in the url, e.g. like **[this](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?as_subj=eng&q=filter)**.

I was able to find the old Advanced Search interface in Google cache: 
[image: screenshot]

**[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKfzh.png)** is a larger screenshot from the same cached version.

However, now I am only able to get to Advanced Scholar Search which looks like this:
[image]

---

So my questions are:

> - Is it possible to find the option to select subject areas?
> - Does adding `as_subj=eng` has the same effect as before?

---

EDIT:

As I learned **[here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/websearch/pa3JNu95gZk)**, you can still get to the old interface like this: `http://scholar.google.com/schhp?sciui=2&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5`.

However I do not know whether they plan to get rid of the old interface eventually. I also tried a few searches and it seems that results are different: Example: **[old interface](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?as_subj=eng&sciui=2&q=filter)** vs. **[new interface](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?as_subj=eng&sciui=1&q=filter)**.

Anyway, I still would be glad if someone could add official information from Google.

EDIT 2 (2013/03/15): Perhaps I should add that now there is no difference between the behavior of the two links above, so I do not know about any way to access the old interface anymore.

Comment: BTW I was somewhat hesitant whether this should be posted in webapps.SE or [academia.SE](http://academia.stackexchange.com/). (Or perhaps a completely different site.) I hope this was the correct choice.

Comment: You should contact google about this. You can contact here: http://support.google.com/scholar/bin/request.py?contact_type=general

Comment: @myselfpoddar I've tried to do so. In case I get any feedback from them, I'll post it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It had been [gone in redesign](http://www.seroundtable.com/google-scholar-redesign-15195.html) few months before you asked this question and most probably you had enough time to assure yourself it won't return ever.

One mitigation would be adding those keywords from topic to search query text. The other could be limiting search down to particular publishing site with *site:example.com/path* stem, **if** you know that info in advance.